# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fill' of undefined

Tags: magento-1.9

I can't understand because when I include a bit of javascript code, only for testing something in Magento, the following error returns:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fill' of undefined
at klass.onComplete (ceramic-sinks.html?p=1&dir=asc&limit=21&mode=grid&order=position&cat=205:4525)
at klass.<anonymous> (ezzoom.js:2)
at prototype.js:1
at klass.<anonymous> (ezzoom.js:2)
at prototype.js:1
```

Anyone could give me an example of how a testing code should be?

This is the code I tested:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {

new Ajax.JSONRequest('http://www.abcd.com/ezzoom/hole/fill', {
    parameters: {isAjax: true,
             id:    '1090382',
             key:   'eJw1ybESgjAQhOFcJ5IlcXgDLSyU1rFxzlxchBsIYS6HBU8vjtrt/y3SZGAy8nB+73ztGgxKS1nmToljFXL6QSG8SLHmTTg+aRkND7JeP/Afu1wi01AQolKS8K2qtzRi7aJhhgOLgkrAKEkM3iFljuhUGFk5KuZcXMQkTwi0/XWDW9ue76fL4Xh9A5CyPlI=',
             holes: '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'
    },
    onComplete: function(transport) {
        var json = transport.responseJSON;

                    for(var i=0;i<json.fill.length;i++){
                      var obj = json.fill[i];
                       $('ezzoom-'+obj.block).update(obj.data);
                    }

                    if (json.conversionRate) 
            convertFromJson(json);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is this `transport.responseJSON`?

Comment: `transport.responseJSON` is undefined/null

Comment: Can you please more of your code what is json ? From the looks of it json.fill is undefined meaning that you json.fill has to be defined somewhere.

Comment: @Ele [`response.responseJSON`](https://github.com/dandean/Ajax.JSONRequest) seems to be a part of the [`dandean/Ajax.JSONRequest`](https://github.com/dandean/Ajax.JSONRequest) repo and the documentation seems to mention it. OP you need to look at your network tab to figure out what response you're actually getting from your ajax request. You _might_ also have to specify `format: 'json'` as per the documentation.